# Wordpress theme's index.php is not showing updates in browser's source. Godaddy hosting

Tags: php, file-permissions, cache, wordpress, godaddy

I've run into an issue with a client's Wordpress site, which is hosted on godaddy (Ultimate Web Hosting Linux)

I'm trying to update their theme's index.php file. Any changes that I make to that file never appear when I try to view source in any browser I've tried, but I can update header.php, and footer.php without any issues.

At first I thought it may be a permissions issue, yet when I edit the index.php file using Godaddy's online file editor, I can see my edits are there.

Godaddy's support responded with "it appears HTML formatting within the PHP coding is not compatible with the document type in use and, as such, the browsers are unable to correctly render the content." The document type from the source is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
```

The content I've tried is straight text and an HTML comment as below:

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

Today I deleted the file on the server to no effect. The page still loads perfectly.

I am absolutely stumped here. Is Godaddy using some sort of cache for this one file?

Comment: I assume you have cleared your cache?

Comment: Cleared cache, and tried it on 2 computers and used Chrome, Firefox, Seamonkey, and Internet Explorer. Like I said earlier, totally stumped here.

Comment: There is something else going on. I use the same service godaddy does not cache content

Comment: Yes, the problem problem is that I'm apparently blind :) Didn't notice the home.php on the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<facepalm>
```

I was editing the wrong file.

```
</facepalm>
```

Just a reminder to everyone, check to make sure there isn't another file overriding your index.php file. In my case it was an unnoticed home.php. I edited it, and the problem was fixed.